# How to draw a little square with a pic on it with fltk

Tags: c++, image, draw, fltk

i wanna create a board with little squares , and put a picture on every square , how can I do it using fltk on c++ ?

Comment: Programming anything is done in short stages.  Right now, it's unclear whether you even have a program that compiles and links with FLTK, if you know how to write a `main` function, or initialize the library.  Beyond that, you haven't specified where your "picture" comes from, how many squares there are, what shape the board is, or anything.  Your question needs more clarity and your problem needs more thought.  Get as far as you can, then show your code and narrow down the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: I only wanna know how to display a box with a picture on it on c++ using fltk ,that's it !

Comment: So, is that a 2D or 3D box?

Comment: a 2D box , a square with a pic displayed inside of it

Comment: Have you read any of the [documentation](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/drawing.html#drawing_images)?

Comment: yes I did , but still couldn't do it

Comment: So... where is the code for your attempt? What specific problem did you encounter?  What part of the documentation did you not understand?  Edit your question and show all relevant information.

Comment: can't you just help me with it if you know how to ? I didn't ask a question to have more questions , I have no code i only wanna draw ONE box with a picture displayed inside of it , the question is as simple as that .. so please that would be really useful if you could actually help me

Comment: I've never used FLTK, but if I were to do so then I would start by reading the documentation, looking at relevant example material, following the documentation links related to the parts I'm interested in and trying to form a better understanding of how the library is intended to be used.  Then, I'd write a minimal example program to start with just a window, then add a basic control, then try to load an image of whatever format I'm trying to display, then try to use the drawing functions.  Only after doing that, and failing to troubleshoot, would I ask a question including _my code attempt_.

Comment: One of the examples on Erco's page does exactly what you need: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended method to draw a box with an image in FLTK is to use an Fl_Box widget and assign an image to it which will be used as its label, like:

```
Fl_Box b(0, 0, 100, 100);
b.image(my_image);
```

Of course, my_image needs to be a valid image like Fl_Image, Fl_PNG_Image etc.